# AlertDialog with custom view doesn't "resize"

Tags: android, android-layout, android-alertdialog, android-dialog

I'm facing a problem with the AlertDialog and custom content / view. Simply said the AlertDialog doesn't resize itself when the softkeyboard is opened. The following screenshots show best what my problem is and what I want to achieve:

Current behavior (left) & wanted behavior (right)

[image: Current behavior] [image: wanted behavior]

I know there a some other threads with a similar issue on SO. Unfortunately none of the provided solutions worked for me. Following my sample code:

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        </EditText>
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Java - CustomAlertDialog.class

```
public class CustomAlertDialog extends AlertDialog{

    private Context context;

    public CustomAlertDialog(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void buildDialog(){
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_content, null);
        builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        builder.setTitle("EditText");
        builder.setView(layout);
        builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                dismiss();
            }
        });
        builder.create();
    }

    public void showDialog(){
        builder.show();
    }
}
```

The class / function above is called on a button press in my Main.java class

```
btnAlertDialog.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            CustomAlertDialog dialog = new CustomAlertDialog(Main.this);
            dialog.buildDialog();
            dialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
            dialog.showDialog();
        }
    });
```

I've tried the following things:

Adding scrollbars to the LinearLayout like this

```
android:scrollbars="vertical" 
android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
```

Result: nothing changed

Setting a flag for the dialog:

```
dialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
```

Result: nothing changed

Applying a custom-style to the AlertDialog:

```
<style name="AlertDialog" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">false</item>
</style>
```

Java

```
builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context, R.style.AlertDialog);
```

This worked. Unfortunately it produced some problems which you can see the in the following screenshot

[image: Custom style - new problem]

I appreciate any help since I've been struggling with this issue for days. Thanks!

## **Solution**

I'm now using the following method to create the Dialog in my `CustomAlertDialog.class`. See my comment below the answer of [nandeesh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1109425/nandeesh) for further details why it didn't worked before.

```
public void startDialog(){
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_content, null);
        builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        builder.setTitle("EditText");
        builder.setView(layout);
        builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                dismiss();
            }
        });
        AlertDialog aDialog = builder.create();
        aDialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
        aDialog.show();
    }
```

Comment: use layout weights. not match parent

Comment: match_parent is perfectly fine for the width. Furthermore it's not possible to give a single LinearLayout a weight.

Comment: well basically the buttons wont show because you are using custom view to the dialog. and after you gave it specific theme the button showed. i would use custom buttons as well if i'd created a custom view to the dialog.

Comment: Well the magic wasn't the theme itself, it was the <item>. Using custom buttons would result in the same problem + the fact that I'd have to apply a specific style for the different api-levels. The AlertDialog handles the api-specific styles by itself. That's why I want to use an AlerDialog rather than custom stuff.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I am not sure where you did the setSoftInputmode
but   instead of

```
builder.show();
```

use

```
AlertDialog mDialog = builder.create();
mDialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
mDialog.show();
```

If this does not work, then do post the CustomAlertDialog class

Comment: Awesome, now it works. I've edited my question with the full code of my `CustomAlertDialog.class`. It seems like the problem was that I've never created an AlertDialog explicitly. So when I set the flag in my Main.class it had no effect since the displayed Dialog wasn't the dialog of my `Main.class` but the builder. 
Now I set the flag in the CustomAlertDialog class and explicitly create an AlertDialog and it works. Thanks again, you led me to the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly this Problem has nothing to do with how the Dialog is built, if you use a custom View etc, the problem is windowSoftInputMode.

Changing the windowSoftInputMode in the AndroidManifest.xml for the Activity in addition to changing it for the Window should do the trick.

Make sure your view in the dialog is a ScrollView.

Comment: Applying `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` to my activity doesn't do the trick, I've also tried this before and according to the reference manual this will only affect the main window. Furthermore: As you can see in my xml-code there is a scrollview and it works without a problem if there are more rows than will fit on the >whole< screen